# Django: Choosing json file in a form and parsing it in a view

Tags: python, json, django

I have the following form:

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="file_id" style="margin-right:1em;">Import Innovations as JSON</label>
        <input type="file" id="file_id">
        <button style="margin-left:2em;" type="submit">Import</button>
    </form>
```

my view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            file = request.FILES
            # do some parsing and create the object here
```

What I'm trying to do is to choose the json file and parse it, then using those values create an object defined in my models.py, the problem is I can't open the json file to parse it, I tried doing `file = request.FILES.read()` but I get `'MultiValueDict' object has no attribute 'read'`. I also tried `json.loads(request.POST)` but I'm getting the following error: 
`the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict`.
 I don't need to save the json file anywhere, I only need it temporarily for parsing. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select a name for your file input first.

```
<input type='file' name='jsonfile'>
```

Then get the file by it's name as key:

```
file=request.FILES['jsonfile']
```

Comment: I completely forgot this aspect of forms, I've been trying stuff for so long my brain kinda started malfunctioning. Thanks.

Comment: @gigamarr its better to create a simple django form class and render it. Django will render all attributes you need in fields.